# In jekyll how to hide <!--more--> in final pages when I use <!--more--> as excerpt_separator?

Tags: jekyll

I use  as excerpt_separator in Jekyll and use {{post.excerpt}} to generate excerpt. It works fine except that in the final page, the "" is replace with "<!-- more -->", so the  can be seen in the final pages. How to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems the <!--more--> in my question is omitted and "&lt;!-- more --&gt;" is replaced with <!--more-->. This is my origin question:

I use <!--more--> as excerpt_separator in Jekyll and use {{post.excerpt}} to generate excerpt. It works fine except that in the final page, the "<!--more-->" is replace with "&lt;!-- more --&gt;", so the <!--more--> can be seen in the final pages. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an html comment, why shouldn't Jekyll output it? It is entirely correct that Jekyll outputs any html you write.

Why don't you simply specify an excerpt in your post front-matter, Jekyll will use that to generate the excerpt and you don't need to specify a separator.

```
---
layout: post
excerpt: my awesome post excerpt…
---
```

Comment: As </p> in markdown would be kept unchanged in final html file and displayed as a new paragraph. I think is reasonable that <!-- more --> kept unchanged. It seems that it's a bug of the markdown render redcarpet, and problem have been solved by changing the render to kramdown.

Answer (score 0):

The `{{ content }}` tag contents all post content, with the excerpt_separator.

Use :

`{{ post.excerpt }}` -> the excerpt
`{{ post. content }}` -> the content = only text after the excerpt_separator

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's a bug of the markdown render redcarpet, and problem have been solved by changing the render to kramdown. In fact, kramdown is the default markdown render of jekyll's default theme, generated by "jekyll new" command. The reason I was caught in this problem is that I used another theme "jekyll-clean", which employ as redcarpet default render, in _config.yml .